# Migrating a local mysql database to heroku postgres from a cakephp application

Tags: mysql, postgresql, cakephp, heroku

Hi I'm trying to migrate a database that was created with cakePHP on a local MYSQL database.  I know that in rails the solution is to install the postgres gem that will handle the migration, but I'm wondering more specifically about cakePHP.

I've generated a sqldump of the mysql database using the solution here: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html

I've also installed postgres locally onto my machine and am able to connect to my remote empty HEROKU database from the command line by using `heroku pg:psql`

However, if I run the SQL dump file directly in the console I get an error called `SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort.`  This apparently is because as a DEV / Free database account you are restricted from entering SQL commands directly.

So, that would suggest that I would have to go and use something like

```
heroku db:push localdatabase herokudatabase
```

But that produces the error `Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: 193: not a valid Win32 application`

Any ideas how I might manage this migration, bearing in mind that as it's a CakePHP application I do not have the option of just installing a PostGres gem?

Thanks for any direction, or thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to install Postgres locally on your machine, and get your database and code working correctly there. Once it's set up, it's easy to do a dump of your Postgres database and upload to Heroku.